# How can I create multiple image sizes at the same time?

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow, android, multiple-sizes

I program Android apps, and one of the requirements is that there are images of multiple sizes generated for different sized devices. I might create a 48x48, 64x64, 96x96, 128x128, and 144x144 image all at the same time, from the same vector. I do virtually all of my image creation for such using Adobe Illustrator CS4. Is there a way to easily create multiple images at the same time?

For reference, here's my typical process:

1. File-> Save for Web and Devices
2. Set the image size
3. Save the image
4. Copy to an appropriate folder
5. Repeat until all image sizes are complete

Comment: There is a similar question on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/478144/illustrator-automatically-export-multiple-different-sized-images-from-project

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/how-to-automate-exporting-multiple-pngs-with-different-sizes-from-photoshop

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `Actions` palette.

You can create an action or set of actions that could automate the resizing and saving process as a batch on the final artwork.

Hope this helps.